# Failing Assertion does not fail the current test case in nightwatch

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js, cucumberjs

I have the below code:

```
var mismatch = 10;
var expected = 0;
if (mismatch <= expected) {

} else {
    return client.assert.equal(mismatch, expected, "Images do not match");
}
```

Event the assert.equal fails, in the hooks file , the test case status is displayed as passed. How to solve this ???

Comment: can you add little bit more code/logic here ? can you cross check one more time your increment/decrements operations locally ?

Answer (score 0):

Here, I am wondering how you used return on assert.equal. As I knows, assert won't provide any value and we can't return it. It will just perform validation between expected and actual value.

Coming to the point, use 'expect' from 'chai' to make your test case/step to get failed when validation is failed and remove return keyword

expect(actual).to.equal(expected, 'test cases failed message');

Hope this helps..